# Границы деепричастного оборота: два или один?

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

При выполнении задания возник вопрос, связанный с верным выделением деепричастных оборотов. Вот предложение:

*"Вода прибывала, заплёскивая и качая прибрежные кусты"* (М. Горький)

Подскажите, как верно выделить границы деепричастного оборота (а точнее, оборотов, как я считаю). По моему мнению, здесь будет два однородных ДО с зависимым словом "кусты" (т. е. заплёскивая (что?) кусты и качая (что?) опять-таки всё те же кусты.
Разберитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь **один деепричастный оборот**, но в его состав входят два деепричастия, связанные сочинительной союзной связью.

Дополнение действительно относится **к обоим деепричастиям,** но такую же грамматику мы видим в предложении с однородными сказуемыми: *Вода заплескивала и качала прибрежные кусты.*